# Callback URL not approved for this client application

Tags: java, android, twitter

Twitter SDK 3.1.0

My Android application crashed and this is the error in the log

code":415,"message":"Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings

I searched for the solution in the doc and I found this message

If you use a callback URL that hasn't been whitelisted, you will receive the following error message

I tried everything and nothing worked

what should I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add twittersdk:// as one callback URL on your twitter app setting 
https://apps.twitter.com/ and it will work as a magic

Comment: I was stuck since last two days Marwa Egyptian.

Comment: @MarwaEltayeb It's not working for me. is there any change on new API's